# Android ListView. Vertical scrollbar isn't visible always for wide list

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have ListView which is wider than parent view. To have horizontal scrolling I've wrapped it with HorizontalScrollView.

Simplified layout XML:

```
<HorizontalScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/main"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

        <ListView 
            android:id="@+id/children"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            />
    </RelativeLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

So that I have vertical scrollbar in the ListView and horizontal scrollbar in the HorizontalScrollView.

My problem is that I don't see vertical list scrollbar unless the HorizontalScrollView isn't scrolled to the rightest position. Because vertical scrollbar along the right edge of the ListView.

Is there a way to make vertical scrollbar visible along the right edge of HorizontalScrollView?
To make list vertical scrollbar visible in any HorizontalScrollView position.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this problem?  I am running into the same problem for a component in my application.  If there's a built in way to keep the vertical bar always visible, I would like to take advantage of it.

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't find a solution :(

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
<HorizontalScrollView 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:scrollbars="none">

            <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/main"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:orientation="horizontal">

                    <ListView android:id="@+id/children"
                        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                        android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
        </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Comment: Thank you for answer.
I've tried your code. But it didn't help. :( In result only horizontal scrollbar disappeared.